# Devise token auth gem querying database twice for authenticating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `devise token auth` gem in my `Rails 5 API`  for authentication.

```
class V1::HuntsController < V1::MainController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
  end
end
```

But when I look at my logs, I see that there is two database queries to find the user. One from `before_action :authenticate_user` and the other from `update_auth_header` from `after_action` added by `DeviseTokenAuth` module.

```
Started POST "/v1/hunts" for 192.168.0.103 at 2016-12-07 15:41:03 +0530
Processing by V1::HuntsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"title"=>"dddd", "clue"=>"dd", "hunt"=>{"title"=>"dddd", "clue"=>"dd"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = ? LIMIT ?  [["uid", "raj@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 204 No Content in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Why is it firing another database query for user when `current_user` is already available? The database query doesnt seem to be cached also as it takes the same time to load.

I doubt if this is due to the default behavior in which token changes with each request. I have disabled this in my `configuration`.

Comment: best option for API authentication is `jwt`

Comment: yes, i also observed simillar thing in my controller, can you paste your method as well.

Comment: @uzaif yes.. but ``devise_token_auth`` was enough for my purpose.

Comment: @user3775217 i kept the action empty to make sure this is being run because of ``devse_token_auth``. This returns no content. The second ``query`` comes from ``update_auth_header`` callback